# Finding range of test results at least as extreme to calculate p-value

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, p-value

Suppose we want to test if a coin is biased towards heads. We decide to toss the coin 10 times and record the number of heads.

Let $X$ denote the number of heads occurring in 10 independent tosses of the coin. and will carry out a hypothesis test with $X$ as the test statistic.

Let $H$ be the event that the coin lands on head, in a single toss. Set our hypothesis to be

$$H_0:P(H)=0.5$$
$$H_1:P(H)>0.5$$

Suppose in our execution of the $10$ tosses, we observe $4$ heads. This means $X=4$ is the test result we observe.

I believe the range of test results that are 'at least as extreme as the one observed' (in the context of finding the p-value) is $$4 \leq X \leq 10$$
as we are testing whether the coin is biased towards heads, thus requiring to us to find test results that have at least as many heads. Is this valid?

Comment: With that alternative hypothesis, what you have said is valid.  If $H_1$ had been $P(H)\not= 0.5$ then "at least as extreme" would have been $\{X\le 4 \} \cup \{X\ge 6\}$

Comment: @Henry this comment is better suited as an answer instead